# error code 401000 from documentation Translator text 3.0

Tags: curl, authorization, microsoft-translator

```
curl -X POST "https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com/translate?api-version=3.0&to=zh-Hans" -H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: 972e6070611c4f8a93baae1b263276ea" -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8" -d "[{'Text':'Hello, what is your name?'}]"
```

i try this code and i have this code error 401000 from the documentation microsoft translator text 3.0

```
{"error":{"code":401000,"message":"The request is not authorized because credentials are missing or invalid."}}
```

i don't know why please help

Answer (score 0):

Did you create a Translator Text resource (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/cognitive-services-apis-create-account?tabs=singleservice%2Cwindows) or a multi-service resource (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/cognitive-services-apis-create-account?tabs=multiservice%2Cwindows)?

If you are using the multi-service resource, please ensure you pass in the region header - 'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Region: YOUR_SUBSCRIPTION_REGION'